# Controlling output of gradient descent class in Python

Tags: python, floating-point, gradient-descent, exponentiation

I've created a LinearRegression class as part of a homework problem, but the outputs I get display crazy amounts of decimal points along with scientific notation. I would really love if my output only displayed values to just a few decimal points.

I've tried giving f-string and format a try. Those *do* reduce the number of decimals displayed, but the scientific notation remains in the output, and occasionally some values just display as 'inf'. Examples below.

If I test this out with the following (as per the assignment):

```
from model import LinearRegression # model.py is my file

model = LinearRegression()
examples = list(range(1, 1000))
values = list(range(1, 1000))

for i in range(len(examples)):
    model.addSample(examples[i], values[i])

print(model.fit(0.0006, 100))
```

I get the output:

```
(2.1803197675124753549e+229, 1.4528186498977718021e+232, 1.7775211633675145435e+465)
```

When I add formatting (e.g., returning '{:.4}'.format(self.theta_0) in my class's fit() method), I get:

```
('2.18e+229', '1.453e+232', 'inf')
```

I'm really not sure why it's being so finicky. There must be something I'm missing. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'{:.4f}'.format(self.theta_0)

OR

import numpy as np

np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)

Comment: Maybe I'm not adding those in correctly... but I still get the output: ('2.18e+229', '1.453e+232', 'inf')

Comment: Why might my mean squared error output as 'inf' after formatting? It wasn't like that before

Comment: Also, would changing the print options work if my values are returned?

Comment: I think mse is much larger than the first two,so it can not be properly printed. To display that,you can try decimal library. And changing print function option would also work